# C# HttpClient not sending post request content, response ends prematurely

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to test a client wrapper for a REST API. It sends a post request using the following code:

```cs
        protected async Task<Response<T>> PostAsync<T>(
            string endpoint,
            object payload,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, endpoint);

            request.AddContent(new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

            var response = await HttpClient
                .SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);

            return await Response<T>.CreateAsync(response);
        }
```

However, in testing it, I repeatedly get a "response ended prematurely" error.

I then tested it against a python script that is essentially `netcat` and saw that it doesn't appear to send the content payload either, only the headers. Even though I sent a well-formatted 500 response back, it still complains of prematurely ending responses.

What could be causing this?

Comment: In which line is the exception thrown? Did you check if there is an `InnerException` that gives more information?

Comment: @RobertoFerraris The exception is a HttpRequestException with an innner IOException. The trace reports HttpConnection.FillAsync as the culprit. The exception is thrown in System code; no line number.

Comment: I think the problem is the `ConfigureAwait(false)`. I understand from documentation that it changes the context of the code execution, so probably didn't work with action/controller logic. I imagine that the action response must be executed in the same context of the request. Can you try to remove it? This is a post about the [ConfigureAwait](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/) that I found to understand the use of this method.